# Changing code on a production server is evil: But what's the best way to handle it, if you do it?

Tags: database, workflow, standards, production

Changing code on a production system to quick-fix a problem is seductive. Even if you know it's evil and bad and dangerous - the day comes you ignore the facts and do it nevertheless.

For all of you that go to the dark side from time to time: How do you try to fix the drawbacks? Do you install a SVN (...) Server to track changes on the prod machines? Install a job that compares checksums of files and sends out "remember-you-changed-this"-Mails? Just place a note on the whiteboard? Sync changes back to a development server?

**Added:** I take it as a fact that this kind of bad practice happens. I am not interested in a perfect workflow to avoid this. Or whether it happens more often in PHP or JAVA or COBOL projects. Or in small vs. big projects. In newbie vs. veteran projects. Or if you get immediately punished by a cosmic entity if you do it. I am simply interested in creative usable tips from people that know how to handle that kind of situation.

Comment: Woe be unto you who code directly to the production environment. If you can't afford a staging machine (or believe that it's faster to screw the pooch and create a panic amongst your customer and staff) then you will get what you deserve.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: He who is capable of creating panic amongst his herd is interested in suggestions to roll the panic back.

Comment: See some of the answers below (specifically from DOK) but bear in mind that life will suck eventually when you do this.  Maybe the first time, maybe the 10th time but it WILL suck.  Narveson and cthulhu's suggestions are really to test on dev and deploy on production which is NOT what you asked for.

Comment: Please don't be picky at my comment I just wanted to sound like a bible verse, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Have a rollback plan** in case the quick fix doesn't work.

For a website, it may be as simple as copying the whole thing to a backup folder.

Often, this entails having a database script to undo changes made in database scripts.

**Have a smoke test** so you can tell immediately if you have broken the application.

Comment: By the time you've done all this - you could have properly tested and deployed.  BTW, I like your answer, but I hate the question.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it......make the change in source control, deploy to your System Test/UAT environment, test  the change, then deploy to Production.

Otherwise, how do you know your 'fix' worked?

Comment: It's not uncommon in the world of fire-and-forget forking servers with PHP that a fix is considered to work because the developer immediately gets back a visible result in the browser. This is one reason so many things are considered to be fixed quickly (I don't support that).

Answer (score 0):

Funny you should ask, since my boss asked me to make a quick change in production just last night.

Except it wasn't quite as quick and dirty as what you may be asking about.  I made the change in our development environment first, then ran the job using a copy of production data and verified the results. On the administrative side, I created a bug ticket to document what I was doing.

And of course I made backup copies of the production code before I copied the change in from development.

No matter how quick and simple the fix and how sure you are that it's what you need to do, I hope you at least made backup copies.

Comment: Note that you're not doing what the OP asked, you tested it in the dev environment first :) He said "Changing code on a production system to quick-fix a problem" (so no testing would have been done)

Answer (score 0):

Use a version control system and, in that, have a 'stable' branch (or use the trunk as the stable component). Put a requirement in there that everything in that branch (or the trunk) should be suitable for immediate deployment at any given time. And add a warning that whoever breaks that branch / trunk shall die or some other painful punishment.

Adding automated testing will also give you confidence in such things - if the tests succeed, you can presume a deploy on the live server will be no problem. Of course, it takes quite a big investment in time (and, consequently, money) to set up such an environment (and maintain it), plus you'd have to convince the management.

It's also a big plus if you have a test environment that behaves exactly like the production environment - same or comparable data, hardware, operating system, versions of third party software and runtimes, and if your production environment is a clustered one (multiple webservers, for example), make sure your test environment has that too - this could be done using virtual machines, if I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

Cowboy Coding: http://www.bnj.com/cowboy-coding-pink-sombrero/

Though a funny appearance it seems a noteworthy approach. By giving this "visual feedback" not only everyone knows, that there is trouble on production, but it also encourages everyone to improve the workflow to minimize "pink sombrero" time.